# Soundfile descriptions are only in the Metadata  - Is there an easy way of working with these?

Tags: metadata, pro-tools, workflow

I've got a bunch of sounds which only have descriptions in the Metadata of the file. The actual file names are mostly just numbers - S0100583449.wav or similar. Searching through this part of the library is fine, but when I copy them to my work folder and import them into protools it's pretty confusing.

Is there an easy way to work with these?

I'm on PT8, working on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

My personal solution: I wrote a small script to rename wave files using metadata description. Unfortunately its in Perl and hard coded for my special case. But I believe there are some metadata tools on the internet.
You are right - working with names like S0100583449 in clip list sucks.

Comment: Thanks, Binoj. Yes, I think a batch rename is the only way. I just read up on Sound Devices Wave agent and think it might work. I'll try when I've some time.

Answer (score 1):

Those descriptions should be visible in the comments field in the workspace browser (in your windows menu) Just search in there for stuff rather than searching by file name.

Comment: Thanks Brent, but I'm fine searching for stuff, the problem is in pro-tools where I can only see the filename.

Answer (score 1):

I know [soundminer](http://store.soundminer.com/) lets you edit the metadata right there and then save it to the file, but it would be a lot of copy and pasting.  Also I'm not sure you have access to soundminer, and its pretty damn expensive.

"[A Better Finder Rename](http://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/index.html)" is an awesome batch renamer, but I'm not sure how well it handles .wav files, but it definitely does give you access to metadata.  You might find a way to do it through that.

Answer (score 1):

At work we used to use SoundHound to search for sfx as it can read metadata. Then SoundHound would import the files directly into Pro Tools naming them whatever their name is in the metadata. Then we would then export it from Pro Tools as a WAV. Sound long-winded but actually just takes a minute or two depending on how many files you need to change.